# Folland, Chapter 1 Problem 17

Tags: measure-theory

Problem 17: If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on $X$ and $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$  is a sequence of disjoint $\mu^*$-measurable sets, then $\mu^*(E\cap \cup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(E\cap A_j)$ for any $E\subset X$.

I've managed to show that the statement is true if $\mu(E)<+\infty$, by showing that

$$\mu^*(E)\ge \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)+\mu^*(E\cap B^C),$$

where $B=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$, and in addition, that

$$\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap B)+\mu^*(E\cap B^C).$$

Now, if $\mu^*(E)<+\infty$, I can substitute the last result into the previous inequality, then subtract $\mu^*(E\cap B^C)$ from both sides of the result, since I am subtracting a finite number. The result is,

$$\mu^*(E\cap B)\ge \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu^*(E\cap A_j),$$

which is equivalent to

$$\mu^*(E\cap \cup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j)\ge \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j).$$

Finally, because $\mu^*$ is an outer measure, I have easily that

$$\mu^*(E\cap \cup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j)=\mu^*(\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}(E\cap A_j))\le \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j).$$

However, I've failed to prove the result if $\mu^*(E)=\infty$. Perhaps it is not true? Counterexample?

Any thoughts?

Comment: You want $\mu^*(E)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(E\cap A_j)+\mu^*(E\cap B^C)$, not $\geq$, right?

Comment: How do you know that $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap B)+\mu^*(E\cap B^C)$, unless you know $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable?

Comment: $B$ is the union of a countable number of disjoint $\mu^*$-measurable sets, so $B$ is measurable, meaning $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap B)+\mu^*(E\cap B^C)$ for any $E\subset X$.

Comment: My understanding was that the definition of $\mu^*$-measurable indicates $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cup B) + \mu^*(E^C \cup B)$ for any $E$, rather than what you wrote.

Comment: Eric, nope, you have it incorrect. It might be because we're using different letters and it's getting you confused. Here is the definition, direct from Folland: If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on $X$, a set $A\subset X$ is called $\mu^*$-measurable if $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^C)$ for all $E\subset X$. Now if I change my letters it would read: A set $E$ is called $\mu^*$-measurable if $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^C)$ for all $A\subset X$. Hope this helps.

Comment: My mistake. I'm glad you cleared that up for me.

Answer (score 9):

Let $\{A_j\}_{1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of disjoint $\mu^*$-measurable sets and $E\subset X$. By countable subadditivity, $$\mu^*\left(E\cap\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j\right)\right) = \mu^*\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E\cap A_j\right) \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)$$
Let $B_n = \bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j$. For each $n\geq 2$, since $A_n$ is $\mu^*$-measurable we have 
\begin{align*}
\mu^*(E\cap B_n) &= \mu((E\cap B_n)\cap A_n) + \mu^*((E\cap B_n)\cap A_n^c)\\
&= \mu^*(E\cap A_n) + \mu^*(E\cap B_{n-1})
\end{align*}
By induction, 
\begin{align*}
\mu^*(E\cap B_n) &= \mu^*\left(E\cap \bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j\right) + \mu^*\left(\bigcup_{1}^{n}E\cap A_j\right)\\
&= \sum_{1}^{n}\mu^*(E\cap A_j) \ \forall n\geq 1
\end{align*}
So then by monotonicty,
$$\mu^*\left(E\cap \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right) \geq \mu(E\cap B_n) = \sum_{1}^{n}\mu^*(E\cap A_j) \ \forall n\geq 1$$
thus as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we have that $$\mu^*\left(E\cap \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right) \geq \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)$$
therefore $$\mu^*\left(E\cap \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_j\right) = \sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu^*(E\cap A_j)$$

Comment: What is the purpose of $\mu^*(E\cap B_n) &= \mu^*\left(E\cap \bigcup_{1}^{n}A_j\right) + \mu^*\left(\bigcup_{1}^{n}E\cap A_j\right)$?

Comment: @Wolfy I like the answer.  I just had one (probably elementary set theoretic) question: after "by induction", I am not seeing why the sum of those two terms would equal the $\sum_1^n$ blah - part.  Is there something I am missing going from countable subadditivity to finite subadditivity, maybe?

Comment: @User7238 Been a minute since I studied measure theory, let me review this and I will get back to you :)

Comment: @Wolfy I appreciate that very much!  Thank you!

Comment: @Wolfy Hi there!  Any luck? :)

Comment: @User7238 apologies I’ve had no time to review, balancing work and a little 6 month old is a struggle. I’ll review it by this weekend. I’ll try to answer sooner

Comment: @Wolfy no worries!  I do appreciate your time!

Comment: @User7238 Hey, I had a little time to review it. Your question could be a separate answer. Have you tried proving the after "By induction" part for n = 0, n = 1, that could help. If not let me know.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The cases I would distinguish are $\mu^*(E\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) <+\infty$ and $\mu^*(E\cap \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) =+\infty$, rather than $\mu^*(E) = +\infty$ and $\mu^*(E) < +\infty$.

Or said differently, you might just as well substitute $E \to E\cap  \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, since the part of $E$ outside of $ \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ has no relevance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cute alternative solution:

From the outer measure $\mu^*$, we get an outer measure $\mu^*|_{E}$ on $\mathcal{P}(E)$ defined as 
$$ \mu^*|_E(B) := \mu^*(E \cap B). $$
We claim then that each $E \cap A_j$ is $\mu^*|_E$-measurable, which is to say for any $B \subseteq E$ one has 
$$ \mu^*|_E(B) = \mu^*|_E(B \cap (E \cap A_j)) + \mu^*|_E(B \setminus (E \cap A_j)). $$
This of course follows from $\mu^*$-measurability of $A_j$, as 
\begin{align*}
\mu^*|_E(B) = \mu^*(B) &= \mu^*(B \cap A_j) + \mu^*(B \setminus A_j), \\
&= \mu^*(B \cap A_j \cap E) + \mu^*(B \setminus (A_j \cap E)), \\
&= \mu^*|_E(B \cap (E \cap A_j)) + \mu^*|_E(B \setminus (E \cap A_j)). 
\end{align*}
Using this, by Caratheodory's theorem, $\mu^*|_E$ is a measure on the collection of $\mu^*|_E$-measurable sets and therefore, 
\begin{align*}
\mu^*\bigg( E \cap \Big(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\Big)\bigg) &= \mu^*|_E\bigg(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E \cap A_j\bigg), \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu^*|_E(E \cap A_j), \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu^*(E \cap A_j).
\end{align*}